# Adding commas to text depending on variables in AMPscript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email

This is my first post and I'm a newbie when it comes to anything code-related let alone AMPscript so any and all help would be very much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

I'm using AMPscript in the footer of my emails and depending on a contact's subscription preferences, I'd like to dynamically show the groups they're subscribed to. The code seems to be working fine, however, I've noticed that if a person is subscribed to multiple consent groups, I am unable to add any formatting such as commas between the two groups. Rather, the line of text that appears says

> %%EmailAddress%% is subscribed to X Y Z

instead of

> %%EmailAddress%% is subscribed to X, Y, and Z

Does anyone know how I can add the commas in between multiple variables? My code is below.

```ampscript
%%[
Var @econsent, @fconsent, @tconsent, @email, @editorial, @first, @third

Set @email=EmailAddress
Set @econsent=AttributeValue("Consent_EditorialContentEmails")
Set @fconsent=AttributeValue("Consent_FirstPartyEmails")
Set @tconsent=AttributeValue("Consent_ThirdPartyEmails")
Set @editorial='X'
Set @first='Y'
Set @third='Z'

]%%

%%Emailaddr%%</a> is subscribed to receive emails from 
                       
%%[if @econsent == true THEN]%%
X
%%[ENDIF]%% 

%%[if @fconsent == true THEN]%%
Y
%%[ENDIF]%%
  
%%[if @tconsent == true THEN]%%
Z
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Answer (score 2):

Great question. There are a few different approaches, but I'd recommend building a rowset, then looping through the rowset to build the output. The following code will do exactly this. Here are some example outputs based on the consent values:

- `email@email.com is subscribed to receive emails from Y`
- `email@email.com is subscribed to receive emails from Y and Z`
- `email@email.com is subscribed to receive emails from X, Y and Z`

> Note: you asked to format as "X, Y, and Z" but I've formatted as "X, Y and Z" which I believe is more common. However, you can use a comma prefix before the 'and' if you insist in using a [serial comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma). Just change `' and '` in my code to `', and '`.

```ampscript
%%[
Var @econsent, @fconsent, @tconsent, @consentList

/*
Set @econsent=AttributeValue("Consent_EditorialContentEmails")
Set @fconsent=AttributeValue("Consent_FirstPartyEmails")
Set @tconsent=AttributeValue("Consent_ThirdPartyEmails")
*/

set @econsent=true
set @fconsent=true
set @tconsent=true

/* build string for rowset */

if @econsent==true then
   set @consentList = 'X'
endif

if @fconsent==true and not Empty(@consentList) then
   set @consentList = Concat(@consentList, '|Y')
elseif @fconsent==true then 
   set @consentList = 'Y'
endif

if @tconsent==true and not Empty(@consentList) then
   set @consentList = Concat(@consentList, '|Z')
elseif @tconsent==true then
   set @consentList = 'Z'
endif

/* check if more than one value */

if IndexOf(@consentList, '|')>0 then

   var @listRowset, @i, @value, @row, @rowCount

   set @listRowset = BuildRowSetFromString(@consentList, '|')

   set @rowCount = RowCount(@listRowset)

   var @consentList /* reset variable dictionary value to null */

   /* build string */

   for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

      set @row = Row(@listRowset, @i)
      set @value = Field(@row, 1)

      if @i == 1 then /* first row */

        set @consentList = @value

      elseif @rowCount != @i then  /* next rows */

        set @consentList = Concat(@consentList, ', ', @value)

      else /* last row */

        set @consentList = Concat(@consentList, ' and ', @value)

      endif

    next

endif

]%%

%%emailaddr%% is subscribed to receive emails from %%=v(@consentList)=%%
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for your detailed explanation, Eliot! I really appreciate it! I noticed that I'm receiving the following error: The initial end count value for the for loop could not be cast to an integer. Any idea why?

Comment: No idea. The code I supplied above should work. You can schedule a call at eliot.com.au if you want to debug further.